# Finding the max/min turning points of $y=\sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> Use differentiation to show that
>
> $$y = \sin x$$ has a maximum turning point at $\left(\frac{\pi}2, 1\right)$ and a minimum turning point of $\left(\frac{3\pi}2, -1\right)$.

I know that the turning points occur when $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$. So ...

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx} &= \cos x \\[6pt]
\implies\quad \cos x &= 0 \\[6pt]
\implies\quad \cos^{-1}(0) &= 90^\circ
\end{align}$$

$\cos x $ is positive in the 1st and 4th quadrants, so $x = 90^\circ$ or $x = 270^\circ$

I am not sure how to progress from here or if indeed this is the correct approach.

Comment: Stick to radians.  They are the only sensible unit for angle once you reach calculus.

Comment: ah right, I remember that actually.  Do the quadrants still apply when using derivatives?

Comment: The quadrants still apply, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Just change your measures from degrees to radians and you will get $$x=90^\circ = \frac{\pi}{2} \\ x=270^\circ = \frac{3 \pi}{2}$$ If you plug these back in the original equation you will get $$ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1 \\ \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=-1$$ Which gives you your points $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},1\right),\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},-1\right)$ as extrema (maximum and minimum respectively) to the function.

Comment: How can I turn degrees into radians?  Is there a table or something I should learn so I know that $\frac{\pi}{2} = 90$

Comment: @dagda1 the relationship between degrees and radians is that $360^\circ = 2\pi$. So, for example, if you want to convert $30^\circ$ to radians, you take the ratio $\frac{360}{30} = 12$, and divide $2\pi$ to get $\frac{2 \pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{6}$ as the measure in radians. From this you can see that $1^\circ = \frac{\pi}{180}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x) = \sin x$, then $f'(x)=\cos x = 0 \iff x = 90^{\circ}$ or $x = 270^{\circ}$, and $f''(x) = - \sin x$ has $f''(90^{\circ}) = -1< 0$, and $f''(270^{\circ}) = 1 > 0$. Thus the max occurs at $x = 90^{\circ}$, and min happens at $x = 270^{\circ}$.

Comment: THe question asks for proof of a maximum turning point at $(\frac{\pi}2, 1)$ and a minimum turning point of $(\frac{3\pi}2, -1)$

Comment: @dagda1  The argument given here is based on the [Second Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second_derivative_test).

Comment: yes but it did not answer the question